# How to keep the tabs state persistent in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made tabs dynamically from the array list, and there are tabs under the tabs. 
Here is the live sanbox link: https://phs69.csb.app/ 
sandbox code and preview: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-glade-phs69

I have made 3 main tabs and other sub tabs under those 3 main tabs.
I want to keep the tabs state persistant which are under the main tab. 
but I am not able to do that.

Here is the entire code of what I have made so far.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
const productTypesSizeAttributesList = [
  [
    {
      product_type_id: "1",
      attribute_id: "1",
      attribute_name: "Achara Cloth",
      product_type_method_id: 3,
      product_type_type_id: 3,
      product_type_unit_id: 4,
      attribute_gif_url: "https://i.imgur.com/cr0LVC7.jpg",
      attribute_youtube_video: "video id1",
      attribute_value_description_id: "1,2,3,4",
      attribute_value: [
        {
          attributeValue: "Bombay Wear",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "Terry Cotton",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "Nylon",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "Sutti",
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      attribute_description: [
        {
          attributeDescription: "Highest Quality"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "Average Choosed"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "Silky Cloth"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "Old Aged "
        }
      ],
      price_per_m: null
    },
    {
      product_type_id: "1",
      attribute_id: "2",
      attribute_name: "Achara Length",
      product_type_method_id: 3,
      product_type_type_id: 1,
      product_type_unit_id: 3,
      attribute_gif_url: "https://i.imgur.com/cr0LVC7.jpg",
      attribute_youtube_video: "video id2",
      attribute_value_description_id: "5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14",
      attribute_value: [
        {
          attributeValue: "3.5",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "4",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "4.5",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "5",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "5.5",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "6",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "6.5",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "7 ",
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      attribute_description: [
        {
          attributeDescription: "small"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "medium"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "standard"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "standard"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "large"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "large"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "very large"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "very large"
        }
      ],
      price_per_m: "270"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      product_type_id: "2",
      attribute_id: "4",
      attribute_name: "Khadki Cloth",
      product_type_method_id: 3,
      product_type_type_id: 3,
      product_type_unit_id: 3,
      attribute_gif_url: "https://i.imgur.com/cr0LVC7.jpg",
      attribute_youtube_video: "video id4",
      attribute_value_description_id: "10,11",
      attribute_value: [
        {
          attributeValue: "Hand Made",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "Ready Made",
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      attribute_description: [
        {
          attributeDescription: "Mostly Choosed"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "Low Cost"
        }
      ],
      price_per_m: null
    },
    {
      product_type_id: "2",
      attribute_id: "6",
      attribute_name: "khadki Color",
      product_type_method_id: 3,
      product_type_type_id: 3,
      product_type_unit_id: 4,
      attribute_gif_url: "https://i.imgur.com/cr0LVC7.jpg",
      attribute_youtube_video: "video id 6",
      attribute_value_description_id: "19,20",
      attribute_value: [
        {
          attributeValue: "white",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "mix",
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      attribute_description: [
        {
          attributeDescription: "poorly choosed"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "highly choosed"
        }
      ],
      price_per_m: null
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      product_type_id: "3",
      attribute_id: "5",
      attribute_name: "Blouse Size",
      product_type_method_id: 3,
      product_type_type_id: 1,
      product_type_unit_id: 3,
      attribute_gif_url: "https://i.imgur.com/cr0LVC7.jpg",
      attribute_youtube_video: "video id",
      attribute_value_description_id: "15,16,17,18",
      attribute_value: [
        {
          attributeValue: "15",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "20",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "25",
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          attributeValue: "30",
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      attribute_description: [
        {
          attributeDescription: "small"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "medium"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "standard"
        },
        {
          attributeDescription: "large"
        }
      ],
      price_per_m: null
    }
  ]
];

const productTypes = [
  {
    product_type_name: "Achara Cloth"
  },
  {
    product_type_name: "Khadki "
  },
  {
    product_type_name: "Blouse"
  }
];
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ProductTypesTable
        productTypes={productTypes}
        productTypesSizeAttributesList={productTypesSizeAttributesList}
      ></ProductTypesTable>
    </div>
  );

  function ProductTypesTable({ productTypes, productTypesSizeAttributesList }) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

    // product_type_id

    return (
      <div className="size__table__product__types__attributes__container">
        <div className="size__table__product__types__container">
          {productTypes.map((obj, index) => {
            return (
              <ProductTypesTableTabs
                index={index}
                name={obj.product_type_name}
              ></ProductTypesTableTabs>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="size__table__attributes">
          {/* {ProductSizeAttribtutesDivs[value]} */}
          <ProductSizeAttribtutes
            productTypesSizeAttributes={productTypesSizeAttributesList[value]}
          ></ProductSizeAttribtutes>
        </div>
        <div className="total__price__of__size__attribute">
          Total {productTypes[value].product_type_name} Price:
        </div>
      </div>
    );

    function ProductTypesTableTabs({ name, index }) {
      return (
        <div
          className={`size__table__product__types inactive_btn__size__table ${
            index === value && "active_btn__size__table"
          }`}
          onClick={() => {
            setValue(index);
          }}
        >
          <div className="size__table__product__types__title">{name}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  // product size attribute overall boxes
  function ProductSizeAttribtutes({ productTypesSizeAttributes }) {
    return (
      <div>
        {productTypesSizeAttributes.map((obj) => {
          return (
            <ProductSizeAttributesSingle
              obj={obj}
            ></ProductSizeAttributesSingle>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

  function ProductSizeAttributesSingle({ obj }) {
    // const [theTabValue, setTheTabValue] = useState(0);
    // const [container, setContainer] = useState(obj);
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="select__size__attributes__container">
          <div className="select__title__image">
            <div className="attribute_name"> SELECT {obj.attribute_name}:</div>
            <div className="gif__url__video__conversion">
              <div>
                <img src={obj.attribute_gif_url} alt="gif url" height="70px" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <IndividualSelectingAttributeContainer
            obj={obj}
            // container={container}
            // setContainer={setContainer}
          ></IndividualSelectingAttributeContainer>
        </div>

        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  }

  function IndividualSelectingAttributeContainer({ obj }) {
    // const [container, setContainer] = useState(obj.attribute_value);
    // const attributeDescriptionContainer = obj && obj.attribute_description;
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
    return (
      <div className="selecting_size_containers_div">
        {obj.attribute_value.map((objAv, index) => {
          return (
            <SelectingSizeAttributesContainer
              attribute_value={objAv.attributeValue}
              // attribute_description={
              //   // attributeDescriptionContainer &&
              //   // attributeDescriptionContainer[index]
              //   // index
              // }
              container={objAv}
              // container={objAv}
              // setContainer={setContainer}
              value={value}
              index={index}
              setValue={setValue}
            ></SelectingSizeAttributesContainer>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

  // selecting size attributes container
  function SelectingSizeAttributesContainer({
    attribute_value,
    attribute_description,
    container,
    setContainer,
    value,
    index,
    setValue
  }) {
    return (
      <div
        className={`selecting_size_containers_div_tab ${
          index === value && "activated_selected_containers"
        }`}
        onClick={() => {
          setValue(index);
        }}
      >
        <div className="attribute_value">{container.attributeValue}</div>
        {/* <div className="attribute_description">{attribute_description}</div> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Need some help in how to make the sub tabs state persistant and also how to store that particular tab value when that particular sub tab is clicked.

Things work fine but the state is not persistant. When i click second tab in the sub tabs, under the second main tab also, the sub tabs state is changed to second tab.

Images

[image: 1st main tab, clicked in 2nd sub tab]

[image: 2nd main tab, automatically gets clicked in 2nd sub tab]

Comment: The problem is that you use the same state for all the values on top and another one for bottom values. In your case, each section of each tab should use a different state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look here. basically you have to keep the state of all the selected sub tabs in the main componentץ
to make it more efficient (prevent re-renders of all sub tabs) you should have the state in tab / sub tab hierarchy, and pass only the relevant part of it to the sub tab components

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-wing-veye3?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple example of you use case here : https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-yalow-6v2h9?file=/src/App.js

You will need to keep the state of all the selected item in the sub section. This is a very basic example, you can handle the global state better than the example (maybe with a context or something else).[image]